# Pentaho: Kettle/Spoon: Combining multiple data after inserts

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm using Pentaho's Kettle/Spoon to load a Customer. I can't figure out how to join 2 or more transformations together after they're complete

```
     Source
  /    |     \
 A     |      B
  \    |     /
   Insert Data

(Database Alpha)
Source Data 
ID, Name, SSN, Email, CanCall, EmailStatus

(Database Beta) 
A) Inserts the email status table if it doesn't exist then returns the ID
B) Inserts the PII table if it doesn't exist then returns the ID
Insert Data 
EmailStatusTable
1, can_email
2, can_not_email

PII Table
1, "Johnson, John", "todays_date"
2, "Jackson, Jillian", "todays_date"

CustomerTable
1, 1 (PII Table ID), "jjohnson@blah.com", true (can call), 1 (email status table ID) 
2, 2 (PII Table ID), "jill_jack@home.com", false (can call), 2 (email status table ID)
```

I can't figure out how to make the "Insert Data" portion work. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Combination lookup/update

step will solve your problem very easily

[image]

Comment: NAILED IT! This did exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Now I can go to sleep peacefully.

Comment: @JasonMell Kindly mark it as answer if it answes your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags by setting the variables inside the transformations and use those flags values to insert data in the customer table. As mentioned by you, you have to return ID, Here return ID means you have to set that variable as a result or flag inside the transformation. Requirement is very simple. IF you need further help, please reply on the same.